# Function for reverse order of values in an array php

Tags: php, function, reverse

I'm new to PHP and I was asked to write a function that accepts an array as a parameter and then prints the array in reverse order. Here is what I have so far:

```
<?php
  function RevOrder ($arr1) {
    $arr1 == array();
    echo array_reverse($arr1);
  }
  RevOrder (array(1,4,2,5,19,11,28));
?>
```

It is supposed to output 28, 11, 19, 5, 2, 4, 1 but I keep getting an array to string conversion error.

Comment: What is the point of "$arr1 == array();" ?

Comment: I was intending that the variable/parameter of the function should be an array

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
function RevOrder (array $arr1) {
    echo implode(", ", array_reverse($arr1));
}
RevOrder (array(1,4,2,5,19,11,28));
```

But note that this isn't particularly good design - your functions should do one thing. In this case you should instead write a function to print an array according to your liking and then pass it reversed array. Although in this case I guess it's ok to have a helper function for printing the array in reversed order but when you're doing something more complicated you should consider this.

EDIT:

You could do something like this:

```
function printArray(array $arr){
    echo implode(", ", $arr);
}
printArray(array_reverse($arr));
```

As for why you can't just echo array see [this](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.casting)

> Arrays are always converted to the string "Array"; because of this,
>   echo and print can not by themselves show the contents of an array. To
>   view a single element, use a construction such as echo $arr['foo'].
>   See below for tips on viewing the entire contents.

Also I added [type-hints](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php) for array so that when you pass something that's not an array you get an error.

Comment: Thank you, this worked! Can you explain further as to why this works and mine did not? I'm trying to get a better understanding of all these functions. Also, how would you write a function to print an array and then pass it as a reversed array?

Comment: @AndrewThalackal: I've edited the answer for further explanation.

Answer (score 0):

[echo](http://php.net/echo) expects a string while you are passing an array, hence the array to string conversion error. It also looks like you are not properly checking if the param passed is an array. Try this:

```
<?php
function RevOrder($arr1) {
   if (is_array($arr1)) {
        return array_reverse($arr1);
   }

   return false;
}

$reversedArray = RevOrder(array(1,4,2,5,19,11,28));

// Option 1
print_r($reversedArray);

// Option 2
echo(implode(', ', $reversedArray));
```